How to recover from deleted /var/lib/rpm/ SQL database rpm files?
I am on a Fedora Linux machine and made a terrible mistake by accidentally deleting the rpm SQL database files located in /var/lib/rpm. I am not even sure what these files are used for. It seems to be causing issues with any package manager commands I make (e.g. dnf) on the machine.
Here are the files that were accidentally permanently deleted:
/var/lib/rpm/rpmdb.sqlite
/var/lib/rpm/rpmdb.sqlite-shm
/var/lib/rpm/rpmdb.sqlite-wal

How can I recover or re-generate these SQL database files in order to get back to my machine's original state?

I would run sudo rpmdb --rebuilddb in order to recreate it from scratch.

Thanks, For some reason I tried that but when I issue dnf commands, I am still getting these error logs "RPMDB altered outside of DNF" and the dnf command will throw segmentation fault. Any ideas on what else I can do to resolve that?

try a sudo dnf check-update before.

you've deleted you rpm database, the system is fine and healthy, but upgrade/installing packages is going to be complicated because rpm/dnf belivees there isn't any packages (or even a database).
to reconstitute the rpmdatabase is tricky, but there's a few ways to do it
rpm --initdb. This should create a brand new database, but the issue is how to populate the database in a way that makes sense.  ideally it would be 100% of the packages you had installed on the machine.  Here's a way to attempt to capture the packages that were installed, look in /var/log at the dnf* files.  you should be able to see some package names inside those log files.  you may be able to gather a complete list looking through those logs, but of course that may not have everything going back to the installation of the os.
Once you have a list of packages you want to initialize your database, you can just install those packages again, which will install those files, although it's actually going to start laying down the files, which may reset some configuration files.  Another option is just fake the installation of these packages, so that you're just adding records to the rpm database, and not actually laying down the package files.  To do that, you would run: dnf download pkgname  and rpm --install --justdb pkgname*rpm, which would just populate the newly reset rpmdb and not modify the os installation otherwise.

I had same or very similar problem. This is what I did, though it's not 100% ideal.

Install the same version of the OS in a VM.
Make sure to copy the database before installing any updates in the guest OS. Otherwise RPM/DNF would "think" you have the latest packages installed and won't update them.
After replacing the broken files with the ones from the VM update your system.
(Re)install stuff that you had before, like the nvidia drivers.
There may be some old kernels left (ls /boot) for which the system no longer has records that they are installed. I think the cleanest way to deal with them is to install the exact same versions of the RPM packages and then uninstall them. I haven't done this yet. I'll update here when I do.

